# Eloquent , Duda para pedir datos

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola necesito hacer una consulta a la base de datos con varios arrays que me llegan es decir seria un where() pero ¿seria posible enviar arrays? y ¿variables opcionales?

```
public function get_data(Request $request){

    //asesores
    $asesores = $request->input('asesores');
    //clientes
    $clientes = $request->input('clientes');
    //grupos
    $grupos = $request->input('grupos');
    // fecha
    // desde
    $desde = $request->input('desde');
    //hasta
    $hasta = $request->input('hasta');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí es posible «enviar» arrays, por medio de whereIn, tal y como funciona una consulta normal de SQL:

```
$users = User::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses

---

Y sí, también se pueden variables opcionales, por medio de condicionales al momento de elaborar la consulta:

```
$query = User::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3]);

if (isset($request->desde)) {
    $query->whereDateFrom($request->desde);
}

$users = $query->get();
```

Comment: gracias Shaz , lo que es estar centrado en una idea pense que habia que hacer algo en especifico con where. Gracias!